# Quotient map (topology), counterexample

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

> Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g: Y\to Z$ surjective, continuous functions. Proof or disprove, that if $g\circ f$ and $g$ are quotient maps, then $f$ is a quotient map.

I think this is not correct, and I want to give a counterexample.
Suppose $Z=\{\ast\}$ and $f$ is a quotient map.

Let $\emptyset\neq U\subseteq Y$ and $\emptyset\neq f^{-1}(U)\subset X$ be NOT open.
Then $g\circ f(f^{-1}(U))=g(U)\subseteq Z$. Hence $g(U)=\emptyset$ or $g(U)=Z$. Since $U\neq\emptyset$ it is $g(U)=Z$ which is open in $Z$. Since $g$ is continuous it is $U\subseteq Y$ open. Contradiction, because $f^{-1}(U)$ was NOT open.

Is this correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $f$ is a quotient map, then $f$ is a quotient map. Maybe best to assume that $f$ isn't a quotient map.

Comment: Ok. When I do so and assume, that $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ is open, then it follows, that $U$ is open (as shown above). Which means $f$ is a quotient map. In contradiction to the assumption, that $f$ is not a quotient map. Therefore the statement is in general wrong. $f$ has not to be a quotient map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler argument following your idea would be better. For any surjective continuous map $f$, let $Z$ be the point, then $g$ is uniquely defined, and $g\circ f$ and $g$ are automatically quotient maps. Thus if the statement were true, all surjective, continuous maps would be quotient maps, and this is easily seen to be false.

One easy example of such a map is the identity mapping from the discrete topology on two points to the trivial topology on two points. This isn't a quotient map because the preimage of a singleton set is open in the discrete topology, but singletons aren't open in the trivial topology.